# Does the randn function in matlab take values from a normally distributed population

Tags: matlab

I had a question regarding the randn function in matlab.

"randn generates random numbers and matrices whose elements are normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1."

I got this off a website: http://www.math.ufl.edu/help/matlab/randn.html

I just wanted to know if this means that the mean and variance of any randn matix or randn vector generated will be 0 and 1 respectively?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the "population" mean is zero and std is one, but the sample mean and std can have some error and so won't be exact. The bigger the sample,the smaller the error therefore the closer to the values of `0` and `1`. Try this to illustrate this to yourself:

```
n = randn(10,1);
N  = randn(1000000,1);

mean(n)
std(n)

mean(N)
std(N)
```

As Marc Claesen points out, if we were to guarantee that the sample mean and std are 0 and 1 then the sample itself cannot be truly random. To guarantee a mean of zero for example, once the first 9 out of 10 samples have been generated, the 10th number cannot be chosen at random as there is only one number that can make the sample mean zero. It is unique and can be solved for deterministicly and thus the sample is no longer random.

Comment: In addition to this answer, consider that if you would have guarantees that the *sample* mean and variance were always exactly `0` and `1`, respectively, the sampled numbers *cannot* be random (whatever distribution you consider).

Comment: @MarcClaesen Absolutely, I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: @MarcClaesen that is not true. They cannot be independantly normally distributed, but as there are (infinitely) many ways to achieve these moments the numbers can definately be random. (for n >2 or so)

Comment: @Dan's answer is correct. Just to add that if you specifically want to  ensure that you have an array with a mean and standard deviation of exactly 0 and 1 you can subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation of your sample: `x = randn(1000,1); x = (x–mean(x))./std(x)`.

Comment: A better phrase is found in the MATLAB documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html 
"... randn(n) returns an n-by-n matrix containing pseudorandom values *drawn from* the standard normal distribution..."